# Nhibernate Linq Strange Issue

Tags: linq, nhibernate

I am experiencing a strange behavior using Nhibernate linq. I am querying for an entity based on a unique property in the class, although it is not technically the primary key. When I run the query with Nhibernate linq it returns the correct result, but the SQL generated has Select top 2 ... When I run the same query with icriteria there is no "top 2" included in the query. Is there anything obvious I should be looking at?

Comment: Which version of the NHibernate Linq provider are you using?  The one in the NHibernate trunk or the one in NHContrib?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's going to be rather difficult to assess the cause of this without any details.  I would encourage you to step through the code and see why your lambda expression is being sql-ized the way it is.